# Cannot add address object using CLI on Sonicwall NSA2400 (5.9 firmware)

Tags: firewall, command-line-interface, sonicwall

Based on an example from "SonicOS 5.9 Enterprise Command Line Interface Reference Guide" I have tried to add an address object using command below (which is not changed compare to prior firmware):

`address-object "Mail Server" host 192.168.168.33 zone DMZ`

but it throws an error:

`% Error encountered at '^' marker:
% No matching command found.`

and marker shows `"Mail Server"`

Anybody had same problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm using `SonicOS Enhanced 5.9.0.3-117o` and the docs say to do:

`address-object ipv4 "Mail Server" host 192.168.168.33 zone DMZ`

Your missing the `ipv4` before the name of the object.

This is because you can enter one of three address-object types.

```
  fqdn     FQDN Address Object.
  ipv4     IPV4 Address Object.
  mac      MAC Address Object.
```